# Not deleting existing file

Tags: c#, file

If the file exist, I want to delete it first then write the file. here is the code:

```
try
{
    if (File.Exists("qwe.mp4"))
    {
        File.Delete("qwe.mp4");
    }
    File.WriteAllBytes("qwe.mp4", encodedDataAsBytes);                   
}
```

however, when i run the program, it does not delete the existing but it append the previous data to the next. (the first data only 2 sec and after append new data, it gets 4 sec). yet the new data cannot be read meaning it only can be played first 2 sec and the other 2 sec cannot be read.

how should i solve this? i want delete the existing file permanently and create a new file with a new data.

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes` overwrites the content of the file. If data is being appended to the file then some other code is being run. Suggest: step through in a debugger.

Comment: File.WriteAllBytes,
Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

[`File.WriteAllBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) overwrites the file if it already exists so you don't need to explicitly delete it.

Comment: I don't see that behavior. It says in the docs but I seem to have to explicitly delete the file first then call WriteAllBytes().

Comment: I used this method but sometimes the new file begin to write before the exist one is  deleted, any idea about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include Full path of the file for both [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) and [File.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete.aspx)

*you should always use the absolute path to make sure you're looking at the correct file*

```
public static bool Exists(
    string path
)
```

Or else it may be the case that the file is overwritten [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) as it Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file.

**If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.**

Comment: `Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory.` So this is not exactly true, but *you should always use the absolute path* to make sure you're looking at the correct file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want existing content to be overwritten, why not simply create a file stream with `FileMode.Create` like this

```
using (FileStream my_stream = new FileStream("filename.mp4", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
  using (BinaryWriter my_writer = new BinaryWriter(my_stream)) {
    my_writer.Write(my_data);
  }
}
```